# Calculate actual distance using disparity map on Stereo Images

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

I am trying to calculate distance of the object from the camera using the below code.
So the approach is to calculate disparity of the left and right image which will be in matrix format.
Once I get the Disparity, I use the formula Depth  = Baseline * focal length/ Disparity

Two questions here:

1. Why is the Depth coming as negative ?
2. And how to get the actual distance of the object from the camera using Depth matrix. Depth matrix basically gives the distance for each point which I don't want. I want to calculate the actual distance of the object in meters.

   import numpy as np
   import sys
   import cv2
   from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
   %matplotlib inline

   imgL = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Akash Jain/Documents/ZED/LeftDepth/left000005.png', 0)
   imgR = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Akash Jain/Documents/ZED/RightDepth/right000005.png', 0)

   stereo = cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities=16, blockSize=5)
   disparity = stereo.compute(imgL,imgR)
   D= 0.12*0.70*672/disparity
   print("disparity",disparity)
   print("Depth",D)
   plt.imshow(disparity,'gray')
   plt.show()

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure why it is not taking as code

Comment: Is your camera setup parallel and are the images rectified?

Answer (score 2):

The simple `Depth = Baseline * focal length/ Disparity` formula is valid only for the case in which the cameras axes are parallel. Assuming you have good matches, toed-in (converging-axes) cameras will cause negative disparities in some parts of the image plane.

However, the disparity image you posted seems low-quality too, which makes me suspect you have bad matches as well: is it reasonable, given your scene, for the disparity to swing so wildly in the low-middle portion?

Comment: @Paul, I am using ZED Camera. Is this formula applicable for images taken from ZED camera ?

Comment: Any help on how to do stereo rectification in python which can be done before I use this formula to calculate depth.

Comment: The ZED Camera does come with a quite nice SDK https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-examples. If you look at the depth sensing tutorial, you have an example on how to obtain a pointcloud from the camera. The distance to the point is simply sqrt(x^2 + y^2  + z^2) assuming that the pointcloud is centered at the camera (most likely it is).

Comment: Thanks @Paul92 I have gone through this link and was trying to build the pre requisite as mentioned on the site. Getting an error. running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pyzed
copying pyzed\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pyzed
running build_ext
building 'pyzed.sl' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Comment: Also, I do have some images taken from ZED camera... Does it still need ZED camera to be plugged in while calculating distance ?

Comment: @Akash I am not sure what pre requisite you are talking about, but the error you get is mostly a technical issue that the guys from github/support from ZED might be able to help. Theoretically yes, you can feed pre-recorded images to the algorithm and get the same result. However, i don't think their implementation has this feature builtin, so I suggest you try with the camera connected and follow the tutorial as described, then start doing modifications.

Comment: @Paul92 By any chance is there any python equivalent code for depth sensing?